# How to delete a substring within a string

Tags: matlab

I have a string like this

```
a={ {'a', 'b', 'c','d'},{''}, {'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'},{''} }
```

where the two '' are empty {1x1 cell} substrings within the string. How do I delete empty substring like this and end up with

```
a={ {'a', 'b', 'c','d'}, {'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'} }
```

Comment: is this really a string ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi: Nope. It's a cell array of cell arrays of characters.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to matlab and still struggeling with the right terms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare each cell of the outer cell array to `{''}` using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html), then use that as a [logical index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to remove those cells:

```
a(cellfun(@(c) isequal(c, {''}), a)) = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this code to perform what you want:

```
a={ {'a', 'b', 'c','d'},{''}, {'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'},{''} }
j = 1
for i = 1:length(a)
   if ~ ismember( a{i}, '' )
       b{j}=a{i}
       j = j+1
   end
end
```

Then variable `a` would look like:

```
>> a{1}

ans = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'

>> a{2}

ans = 

    'e'    'f'    'g'    'h'
```